# Offline create accounts and sign transactions

Tags: web3js, blockchain, dapp-development, clients, ethereumjs

I have a question about Ethereum client-side, maybe someone could give a hint...

It's about building a DApp, we need a web client capable of creating offline a private key and a public key, and also send signed transactions to an Ethereum node.

After investigating for a while we came to the conclusion this is possible through the web3.js library (and others like ethereumjs), but it implies using nodejs and browserfy, right? The question is:

Is there any other simpler solution, such as using a simple js file?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a wrong assumption. Using Web3.js does not require Browserify or Node.JS. You can drop in web3.js dependency in HTML code like any other JavaScript library. Only building Web3.js distribution requires this build toolchain.

[Here is a simple "index.html" application using web3.js](https://github.com/nordledger/eireg/blob/master/html/index.html).

Comment: Is web3.js enough to create private and public keys? And enough to sign transactions? Or should I use ethereumjs too?

Comment: If you don't need deterministic keys a private key is just any securely random number. web3.js can derive a public key / address from a private key.

Comment: Can I use web3.js as a standalone to sign transaction?

Answer (score 2):

Try the consensys lightwallet

> the txutils functions can be used to construct transactions when offline, for use in e.g. air-gapped coldwallet implementations.

https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet

Comment: Thx! When trying offline eth-lightwallet-master/example/webwallet.html I got these errors on javascript console:

 Uncaught ReferenceError: async is not defined
    at getBalances (webwallet.html:52)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (webwallet.html:154)

Is that normal?